# Net::SSH::Perl is giving error msg No matching cipher found

Tags: perl, ssh

I am using Net::SSH::Perl (pure Perl implementation of ssh) is giving the error

> No matching cipher found: client 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour server
>   aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc

I updated the module to lastest version ... but it did not help.

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl is mostly a dead project, the cipher collection has not been expanded in the last decade. Use some more recent module: on Windows Net::SSH2, on Linux/Unix Net::OpenSSH, or Net::SSH::Any that wraps both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No matching cipher found: client 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour server aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc

That says it all: none of the ciphers supported by the client is supported by the server. Check if you can configure the server to allow any of the ciphers supported by the client.